# set withCredentials to the new ES6 built-in HTTP request API : Fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

How to set `withCredentials=true` to  [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which return promise.
Is the following correct :

```
fetch(url,{
   method:'post',
   headers,
   withCredentials: true
});
```

I think the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) talked about everything about http-requesting except this point: `withCredentials`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Got it [here](https://github.com/github/fetch) :

```
  credentials: 'include'
```

and not

```
  withCredentials: true
```

Comment: It's also in the [official spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials) with an XHR example

Comment: Anyone having issues with adding this config to fetch and still not getting a request cookie sent after logging in?

Comment: It is also could be neccesary to add header `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true` to the server response

Comment: @WilliamChou Me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971278/sending-cookies-in-a-cross-origin-request Have spent days on this and still unresolved.

Comment: @OldGeezer I ran into come CORs issues in a personal project... turns out i had the URL wrong and it wasnt my CORs config, maybe you already solved this but curious to see if it was actually something else unrelated