# Fetch with Credentials and Json Body

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Need to send a `POST` request with a `JSON body`. I have to use `fetch`.

**Original code snippet, which worked:**

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
body = {path: 'path1'};
fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
        .then(response => {//do work});
```

Now I have to add `Http-Only cookies` for `A&A`.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543547/398909) has answer for that. Basically, have to add another parameter.

**Afterwards updated code to:**

```
fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
        .then(response => {//do work});
```

Server doesn't see `cookie` in `header`.

Then tested the `fetch` by removing everything else:

```
fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'post',
    })
        .then(response => {//do work});
```

`A&A` part works i.e. Server now sees `cookie` in `header`. So, added the body back and didn't believe it would work:

```
body = {path: 'path1'};
fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
        .then(response => {//do work});
```

As expected, it didn't work. The `Express` server with `CookieParser` is showing that body is `{}`.

After added the `Content-Type` header:

```
body = {path: 'path1'};
fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
        .then(response => {//do work});
```

Now, the `cookie` has disappeared again. Guessing it's because of adding a new header, and replacing header generated by `fetch`, which includes `cookie`. Am I wrong?

While I was searching I found a [similar question](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/452) with no answer.

How should I proceed?

Comment: In the `headers` you can add a `'cookie' : '{cookie}'`.

Comment: I am working in `React`, and I haven't found a way to read `Http-Only` cookies. That's why I am using `withCredentials` option. Please let me know if I am on the wrong track.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it using another library `axios`. Same situation. If I add the `body`, `cookie` is dropped. Is this a standard? If so, what is the workaround?

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the browser devtools console? Also please consider updating the question to show the response headers you’re getting back from the server in each case (as shown in the Network pane in devtools) — and ideally, also the request headers for each case.

Comment: I figured it out. It's the `OPTIONS` `preflight` request issue. Server needs to handle that. 
And the browser is sending only if there is a body or extra headers. If it is an empty request to get something from server, `OPTIONS` is not sent.

Comment: Hi, Http-Only Cookie are meant not be used by any Javascript in the frontend to avoid security issues. It's why your can't read it in React and you should let the browser handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for sending a json body

```
var postData = {name: 'ram',class: 'five',};

var url = 'https://example.com/api';

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(postData),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```